# How to connect to Google Cloud SQL using native PHP hosted on Hostinger?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I hope they are well, I ask for your help please since I have been researching a lot without finding a solution, I currently have my system hosted in Hostinger, everything worked fine, however I need to migrate the database to Google Cloud SQL, until now I have everything ready, my database is already in the cloud and I was able to connect with workbench, but when connecting from my project there was a problem, my code is:

```
define('DBH_SOCKET', '/tmp/mysql.sock/project-test:us-east1:test');
define('DBH_NAME', 'db_test');
define('DBH_USER', 'admin');
define('DBH_PASSWORD', 'df434hsXsfvr45hgfhd');

$pdo_conn = "mysql:unix_socket=".DBH_SOCKET.";dbname=".DBH_NAME.";charset=utf8";

try {
    $dbconn = new PDO($pdo_conn, DBH_USER, DBH_PASSWORD);
    $dbconn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "<br> db is ".$pdo_conn;
```

with this code I get the following error:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No es un directorio
var is mysql:unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock/project-test:us-east1:test;dbname=db_test;charset=utf8
```

I do not know what is happening or what I am doing wrong since I have asked hostinger what is the path of his socket for the connections and they send me to this link: https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583557- what-is-my-database-socket-path, Because my project is hosted by Hostinger's Cloud Hosting.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your connection is using Unix Sockets. Did you setup the Google Cloud SQL Proxy? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy

Comment: Hi, @JohnHanley Yes, in fact I already managed it, however I did it with the public address method, but now the problem is the speed, when making inserts from my system, it takes up to 2.2 minutes to save 160 records.

Comment: Edit your question to show your current problem.

Comment: ready @JohnHanley

Comment: Since you solved the problem, remove your last edit and post an answer. Then create a new question with your new problem. One question/problem per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with the public address method